# It's not allowed to store backups inside the Drupal root directory

Tags: 7, drush

I must be missing something because I can't determine what I'm doing wrong. I've got a D7 site, and we're running Drush 8.1.10

I'm trying to run through some updates but I keep running into this error:

`It's not allowed to store backups inside the Drupal root directory.`

I don't have the backups directory inside the drupal root directory - or at least so far as I know, it's not. I've set the directory to be one level above the webroot and declared it in my settings.php as follows:

```
/** declaring the private files directory 
*/
$settings['file_private_path'] = '/var/www/vhosts/drush-backups';
```

In my file system I've also got my private files path set to the same to the same dir just trying to figure out where this issue is coming from.

Can someone help me figure out what I'm missing?

Comment: I assume that message is coming from the "Backup and migrate" module. If you disable it, are you able to update with Drush? If I'm right about B&M, I think you should check the module issue queue. You could update your question with version info for B&M.

Comment: Not coming from B&M module - it's disabled and uninstalled. Same issue persists.

Comment: You are correct. Sorry about the non-helpful comment.

This is coming from Drush trying to backup your files before upgrading (or something). Drush doesn't use file_private_path - it uses it's own setting. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26879225/how-to-set-drush-backup-directory